# Is the mixing of $0^{++}$ glueball with isoscalar scalars considered in Lattice QCD calculations so far?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

In PDG 2018, in an article named "[non-$q\bar{q}$ mesons](http://www-pdg.lbl.gov/2018/mobile/reviews/pdf/rpp2018-rev-non-qqbar-mesons-m.pdf)" in the forth paragraph it is mentioned that:

> "*The lattice calculations were performed so far in the quenched approximation. Thus neither quark loops nor mixing with conventional mesons were included, although quenching effects seem to be small.*"

In my opinion this means that so far mixing of glueball with mesons is not considered in Lattice calculations. But I found some articles in which I think the mixing is considered in unquenched QCD, for example: [Gregory *et al.*](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0510066v1), [*Sun et al.*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00711v1).
As my field is not Lattice QCD, taking a look at Lattice papers made me confused. So  I want to be sure if the mixing is considered or not? If yes, why the review of particle physics didn't mention that?

Comment: You may be asking a charged social question. There is keen interest in the lattice community for, and several exploratory efforts on glueball-quarkonium mixing, like the ones you cite. Nevertheless, this mixing has not been understood at the high precision level commanding reliance of the PDG type. You should not judge the creative margins of a field by conservative PDG inclusions.

Comment: @ Zachos, Thanks a lot for your answer. I was just curious to know the reason of not reporting that researches in PDG.

Comment: PDG is conservative and covers "established facts", not ongoing piecemeal efforts. It is a terrible place to start library research if you are into cutting edge theory.